# inheritance in a TreeView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I make a TreeView and there I want to make a function to : when a parent (in my case Root ) is checked all child to be check, and if one child is checked the parent to be check. I know the fact as exists many answers for this question, but for my case doesn't work . Last thing that I tried was the next code, but it don't do anything :

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

}

private void SelectParents(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
{
    var root = node.Parent;

    if (root == null)
        return;

    if (isChecked)
    {
        root.Checked = true; // we should always check parent
        SelectParents(root, true);
    }
    else
    {
        if (root.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Any(n => n.Checked))
            return; // do not uncheck parent if there other checked nodes

        SelectParents(root, false); // otherwise uncheck parent
    }
}
```

I need to define somewhere the `parent` ? How I can make an inheritance in a TreeView?

Comment: Used technology unclear to me.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to get all the parents of a specific node and set them to checked?

Comment: yes, that I want to say

Comment: and if a parent is checked all the children to be check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need a way to get all the parents. A simple extension method could be used here.

```
public static List<TreeNode> Parents(this TreeNode node)
{
    var parents = new List<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
    while (parent != null);
    {
        parents.Add(parent);
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return parents;
}
```

Then you need a way to check all children of the parent, which again can be done with an extension method.

```
public static void CheckChildren(this TreeNode node)
{
    if (!node.Checked)
        return;

    foreach (var node in node.Nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = true;
        node.CheckChildren();
    }
}
```

At last when you check a node you simply call a foreach loop like below.
It will iterate over the parents of the node, check them and their children.

```
foreach (var parent in node.Parents())
{
    parent.Checked = true;
    parent.CheckChildren();
}
```

You could also rewrite the `Parents` method to call `CheckChildren` to prevent you from having to loop and call `CheckChildren` on every iteration.

```
public static CheckParentsAndChildren(this TreeNode node)
{
    TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
    while (parent != null);
    {
        parent.Checked = true;
        parent.CheckChildren();
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return parents;
}
```

All you'd have to do then is

```
node.CheckParentsAndChildren();
```

The extension class could look like this.

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static List<TreeNode> Parents(this TreeNode node)
    {
        var parents = new List<TreeNode>();
        TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
        while (parent != null);
        {
            parents.Add(parent);
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        return parents;
    }

    public static void CheckChildren(this TreeNode node)
    {
        if (!node.Checked)
            return;

        foreach (var node in node.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = true;
            node.CheckChildren();
        }
    }

    public static CheckParentsAndChildren(this TreeNode node)
    {
        TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
        while (parent != null);
        {
            parent.Checked = true;
            parent.CheckChildren();
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        return parents;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I want to put the second code I have the next error : "The name 'nodes'  does not exist in the current context'...

Comment: if i put the next foreach (var parent in node.Parents ()), again I have an error

Comment: how I can do node.CheckParentsAndChildren(); ? and where ?

Comment: You have to put the extension methods in a static class. Otherwise you can't call them as above. If you don't want them as extension methods remove `this` from the parameters and put them wherever you want and them call them like ex. `CheckParentsAndChildren(parent)` etc.

Comment: You can write that class, please, I'm a beginner and I can't handle whit this .

Comment: Added an example of the extension class, but please read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx and if this answer was the solution, please accept it.